# Is it correct to use the concept of phase margin for not so 'well-behaved systems'?

Tags: power-supply, control-system, stability, bode-plot, frequency-response

The [TI document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva301/slva301.pdf?ts=1684155060993&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) mentions the Phase margin as 60 degree for the given bode plot whereas the lowest PM when Gain >1 is around 45 degree.
[image]

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) says: " Ordinarily, as frequency increases the magnitude of the gain drops and the phase becomes more negative, although these are only trends and may be reversed in particular frequency ranges. Unusual gain behavior can render the concepts of gain and phase margin inapplicable. Then other methods such as the Nyquist plot have to be used to assess stability."

1. In those lines is it ok to talk about phase margin for above graph? If so, should we call it as 45 degree or 60 degree?
2. Does this come under the category of conditionally stable systems?

Comment: Thew phase margin is clearly defined. It is defined at the loop gains cross-over frequency (17 kHz). Surprisingly, the shown phase response starts at -90 deg. For frequencies <10 Hz it must approach 0 deg.

Comment: The graphs are not easy to read. In principle, a pole at the origin brings a 90° shift which, added to the 180° shift of the op-amp gives -270° or 90° for \$s\$=0 (see my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399094/determining-phase-boost-needed-to-compensate-smps?rq=1)). In TI's illustration, it seems they did not include the op-amp inversion and measure the phase margin from the -180° line which is also ok. In the AN, the guy misspelled everywhere Vatché's name which is *Vorpérian*: he came up with the concept of the PWM switch model.