# LTC7803 Buck Converter Current Mode Compensation

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, compensation

I wanted to design a step-down converter using the LTC7803. Goal is to have a 5V, 0-2A output with an input voltage range of 10-30V. Switching frequency is set at 1MHz. As shown in the LTSpice picture below, I have already setup most of the functions on the regulator.

[image]

My question is how does one go about choosing the values of the compensation capacitors and resistor on the ITH pin for a given desired phase margin and crossover frequency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is a long story to explain these concepts but before all, you need the *control-to-output* transfer function of your power converter. It means that if you *excite* the control input - which is the output of your error amp, an operational transconductance amplifier or OTA available at the ITH pin - you want to observe how the *stimulus* propagates through the circuit and power stage to form a *response* on your output. In your case, this is \$V_{I_{TH}}\$ to \$V_{out}\$.

The ratio of the response to the stimulus is the transfer function (TF) you want. You can obtain this transfer function using a) a frequency response analyzer (FRA) in the lab b) a set of equations as those given in my last [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/transfer-functions-of-switching-converters/) on the subject or c) use a simulator for this purpose. If you use a SPICE simulator like LTspice, it has a feature to extract the ac response from a switching circuit but, for different reasons, I'm not convinced it is that practical. Therefore, either you resort to an average model for your CM converter - and I have LTspice models you can download from my [page](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm) - or you use a piece-wise linear (PWL) engine like SIMPLIS. This is what I use.

For this approach, you can pick one of my [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) which works on the free demo of the editor, [Elements](https://www.simplistechnologies.com/product/elements). A typical CM buck converter from the collection of circuits is shown below:

[image]

Here, I have an op-amp for the compensator but the comments equally apply for an OTA. So you start to unveil the control-to-output transfer function as shown below:

[image]

Before considering these ac results, *always* check the operating point, e.g. verify that the simulated variables are within expected limits: here I wanted a 5-V output and this is ok. The ac response stands to the right, this is the power stage response and that's what you need. The gain is flat at dc and then goes down with a -1-slope until the damped double poles show up. There is slope compensation hence the absence of peaking. Once there, you have to choose a crossover frequency. I recommend you look at these answers I gave on SE a while back: [crossover](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/657442/smps-control-loops-what-is-crossover-frequency), [buck converter with TI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/654455/what-is-the-texas-instruments-loop-calculator/654506#654506), [phase boost](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399094/determining-phase-boost-needed-to-compensate-smps) but also at my former APEC seminars like [2012](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf).

In this example, I have selected a 10-kHz crossover frequency and I want a 60° phase margin. Simply enter in the automated macro the value of phase and magnitude read at the selected crossover frequency: the gain deficit is 20 dB and the phase lag is 40° at 10 kHz. The macro will automate the calculation and you can check the compensated gain immediately:

[image]

You see a crossover of 8.9 kHz (the op-amp has its own ac response that affects the compensator response) with a good phase margin. A transient step shows a good response to a 1-A load step (1 A/µs).

If you want to determine the compensation values for the OTA specifically, please look at my set of compensated error amps [here](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Divers/Compensators%20SIMPLIS.zip), there is a design example as shown below:

[image]

In a nutshell: crossover frequency is selected for a fast transient response, usually 1-10 kHz in your case, don't push it too far because it is detrimental to stability as noise susceptibility increases with crossover but also because the ac response of the OTA may not keep up. For phase margin, if you want a safe and robust design, shoot for 60-70°. Reducing this value makes the response more nervous but prone to overshoot as it approaches the minimum acceptable limit of 30° (45° is usually an accepted low limit). Increasing phase margin gives the converter a more sluggish but rock-solid transient response. There are plenty of papers and articles detailing these aspects. Good luck with this design!